# Definition of Local Function

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, definition, locality, non-locality

Now a days I am studying Srednicki's QFT book. In its third chapter it is written that

> *Any local function of φ(x) is a Lorentz scalar, [...]* .

Now my question is: What is a local function?

Answer (score 11):

1. Well, the notion of *locality* depends on context.  Usually in the context of QFT, *a local function* means a function of the form
   $$ f(\varphi(x), \partial\varphi(x), \partial^2\varphi(x), \ldots,\partial^N\varphi(x) ;x), $$
   where $N\in\mathbb{N}_0$ is some finite order. This is sometimes called *perturbative local.* (If $N=0$ then the function $f$ is called *ultra-local.*) See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13624/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43721/2451) Phys.SE posts.
2. Concretely, in the mentioned place almost at the end of chapter 3 in Srednicki's book, the phrase

   > *any local function of $\varphi(x)$*

   is used (in a non-standard way) to denote

   > *any function of the form $f(\varphi(x))$,*

   as opposed to, e.g.,

   1. functions of the form $f(\varphi(x),x)$ with explicit $x$-dependence, which may not be a Lorentz scalar,
   2. functions of the form $f(\partial\varphi(x))$, which may not be a Lorentz scalar,
   3. bi-local functions $f(\varphi(x), \varphi(y))$,
   4. functionals $F[\varphi]$,
   5. etc.