# What is meant by a local Lagrangian density?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, definition, locality, non-locality

1. What is meant by a local Lagrangian density?
2. How will a [non-local Lagrangian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlocal_Lagrangian) look like?
3. What is the problem that we do not consider such Lagrangian densities?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54792/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**What is a local Lagrangian density?**

A classical field theory on Minkowski space $\mathbb R^{d,1}$ is specified by a space $\mathcal C$ of field configurations $\phi:\mathbb R^{d,1}\to T$, and an action functional $S:\mathcal C\to\mathbb R$.  The set $T$ is called the target space of the theory, and is often a vector space.  If there exists a function $L:\mathcal C\times\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ for which
\begin{align}
  S[\phi] = \int_{\mathbb R} dt\, L[\phi](t),
\end{align}
then we call $L$ a **lagrangian** for the theory.  If, further, there exists a function $\tilde L$ such that
\begin{align}
  L[\phi](t) = \int_{\mathbb R^d} d^d\mathbf x \,\tilde L[\phi](t, \mathbf x)
\end{align}
then we call $\tilde L$ a **langrangian density** for the theory.  Finally, if there exists a positive integer $n$ and a function $\mathscr L$ such that
\begin{align}
  \tilde L[\phi](t, \mathbf x) = \mathscr L(t,\mathbf x,\phi(t, \mathbf x), \partial\phi(t,\mathbf x), \dots, \partial^n\phi(t,\mathbf x))
\end{align}
then we say that the lagrangian density is **local**.  In other words, the lagrangian density is local provided its value at a given spacetime point depends only on that point, the value of the field at that point, and a finite number of its derivatives at that same point.

**An example of a non-local Lagrangian density.**

Consider $T = \mathbb R$, namely a theory of a single real scalar field.  Let $\mathbf a\in\mathbb R^d$ be given, and define a Lagrangian density by
\begin{align}
  \tilde L[\phi](t,\mathbf x) = \phi(t,\mathbf x) + \phi(t, \mathbf x+\mathbf a).
\end{align}
This Lagrangian density is not local because the value of the Lagrangian at a given point $(t,\mathbf x)$ depends on the value of the field at that point and on the value of the field at the point $(t,\mathbf x+\mathbf a)$.  If we were to Taylor expand the second term $\phi(t,\mathbf a)$ about $\mathbf x$, then we would see that the Lagrangian density depends on an infinite number of derivatives of the field, thus violating the definition of a local Lagrangian density.

**What's the issue with theories with non-local Lagrangian densities?**

I'm no expert on this, so I'll divert to another user.  I will say, however, that people do study theories with non-local Lagrangian densities in practice, so there's nothing a priori "wrong" with them, but they might generically exhibit some pathology that you might prefer not to have.

Perhaps most relevant, though, if you're taking QFT from a high energy theorist, for example, is that the Lagrangian density of the Standard Model is local, so there's no need to consider non-local beasts if one is studying the Standard Model.

Comment: Nice example! I think that the problem with non-local Lagrangian densities is mostly due to the fact that they need some further structure in addition to the natural local geometry and coupling constants (e.g., you introduced a vector ${\bf a}$ in your example) and these structures have never been experimentally observed. Another way to construct non-local Lagrangian densities is employing some smearing function as in the Bopp's model of (non-quantum) electron (discussed in the Feynman Lectures on Physics).

Comment: @V.Moretti Thanks! I see; that's interesting.  I'll take a look at Bopp's model.

Comment: Here is: http://www.feynmanlectures.info/docroot/II_28.html#Ch28-S4 Unfortunately there is not an exhaustive discussion, nor a Lagrangian treatment just the basic non-local idea.