# Legendre transform for non-local Lagrangians, or Hamiltonian of non-local Lagrangian and their properties

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, action, non-locality

This is sort of a multi-part question, mostly dealing with how to treat non-local Hamiltonians and how the corresponding properties of Hamiltonians work in a non-local framework. I proposed an example to make explanation easier, but generalized answers are helpful too.

To start:

How does one apply the Legendre transform to a non-local Lagrangian, or get the Hamiltonian of such a Lagrangian?

For example, given the functional:
$$
F=\frac{1}{2}\int^t_0 \left(\dot{x}(\tau)\dot{x}(t-\tau)-x(\tau)x(t-\tau)\right)\,\text{d}\tau
$$
Which, when varied with respect to the state, is stationary for the system:
$$
\ddot{x}(\tau)-x(\tau)=0
$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $\dot{x}$ of $F$ yields:
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x}}=\frac{1}{2}\int^t_0 \dot{x}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau+\frac{1}{2}\int^t_0 \dot{x}(t-\tau)\,\text{d}\tau=\int^t_0 \dot{x}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$
Would it then be true that?:
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x}}=\int^t_0 p(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$
So we can go on to say:
$$
\int^t_0 \mathcal{H}\,\text{d}\tau=\int^t_0 p(\tau)p(t-\tau)\,\text{d}\tau-\left.F\right|_{\dot{x}=p}
$$
Which gives:
$$
\int^t_0 \mathcal{H}\,\text{d}\tau=\frac{1}{2}\int^t_0 p(\tau)p(t-\tau)+x(\tau)x(t-\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$
So can we say?:
$$
\mathcal{H}=\frac{1}{2}\left(p(\tau)p(t-\tau)+x(\tau)x(t-\tau)\right)
$$
Additionally:
$$
\frac{\text{d}\mathcal{H}}{\text{d}\tau}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\dot{p}(\tau)p(t-\tau)-p(\tau)\dot{p}(t-\tau)+\dot{x}(\tau)x(t-\tau)-\dot{x}(t-\tau)x(\tau)\right)
$$
Would it then be correct to substitute?:
$$
\dot{p}(\tau)=x(\tau)
$$
$$
\dot{p}(t-\tau)=x(t-\tau)
$$
$$
\dot{x}(\tau)=p(\tau)
$$
$$
\dot{x}(t-\tau)=p(t-\tau)
$$
Which gives:
$$
\frac{\text{d}\mathcal{H}}{\text{d}\tau}=\frac{1}{2}\left(u(\tau)p(t-\tau)-p(\tau)u(t-\tau)+p(\tau)x(t-\tau)-p(t-\tau)x(\tau)\right)
$$
Integrating both sides (and making some integration substitutions) then yields:
$$
\int^t_0 \frac{\text{d}\mathcal{H}}{\text{d}\tau} = 0
$$
Would this imply that $\mathcal{H}$ is constant?

Lastly, to get back the equations of motion from $\mathcal{H}$, we have:
From:
$$
 \frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial p}=\dot{x}
$$
and
$$
 \frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial x}=-\dot{p}
$$
We have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\int^t_0 \mathcal{H}\,\text{d}\tau = \int^t_0 \dot{x}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$
Or
$$
\int^t_0 \dot{x}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau=\int^t_0 p(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int^t_0 \mathcal{H}\,\text{d}\tau = \int^t_0 \dot{p}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$
Or
$$
\int^t_0 \dot{p}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau=-\int^t_0 x(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau
$$
This **does not** match the initial equations of motion, is that due to the non-local nature of the formulation? Would we then say that?:

$$
 \frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial p}=\dot{x}
$$
and
$$
 \frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial x}=\dot{p}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let here consider point mechanics (as opposed to field theory) for simplicity, i.e. the generalization to field theory is left as an exercise.

I) *Bad news.* If the Lagrangian action functional $S[q]$ is [non-local](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121816/2451), the usual definition of Lagrangian momenta as a *partial* derivative
$$p_i~:=~\frac{\partial L}{\partial v^i} \tag{1}$$
does not apply.

II) *Good news.* If the (possibly non-local) Lagrangian action functional is of the form 
$$\left. S[q,v]\right|_{v=\dot{q}},  \tag{2}$$ then we can in principle perform a Legendre transformation on the action $S[q,v]$. The Legendre transformation will depend on how we split the action $S[q,v]$ into two *independent$^1$* sets of variables $q^i$ and $v^j$. Nevertheless assume that this splitting $S[q,v]$ has been done. Next define the momentum as a *functional* derivative

$$p_i~:=~\frac{\delta S[q,v]}{\delta v^i} .\tag{3}$$

Now one may in principle perform the Legendre transformation very similar to the standard method outlined in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105912/2451) Phys.SE post, modulo the usual caveats about a possible singular Legendre transformation. Define the Hamiltonian functional$^2$ as

$$\mathbb{H}[q,p]~:=~\sup_{v}\left( \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt~ p(t) v(t) -  S[q,v]  \right). \tag{4}$$

The corresponding Hamilton's eqs. become

$$\dot{q}^i~\approx~ \frac{\delta \mathbb{H}}{\delta p_i},\qquad 
-\dot{p}_i~\approx~ \frac{\delta \mathbb{H}}{\delta q^i}. \tag{5}$$

[Here the $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo eqs. of motion.] We can define a Poisson bracket

$$\{F,G\}_{PB}~:=~\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt~  \frac{\delta F}{\delta q^i(t)}  \frac{\delta G}{\delta p_i(t)}  -(F\leftrightarrow G). \tag{6}$$

Then Hamilton's eqs. (5) can be written as

$$\dot{z}^I(t)~\approx~ \{z^I(t), \mathbb{H}\}_{PB},\tag{7}$$

where $\{z^I\}=\{q^i;p_j\}$ is a collective notation for the phase space variables.

--

$^1$ Note in particular that an action $S[q,v]$ with two *independent* sets of variables $q^i$ and $v^j$ flies in the face of the usual paradigm that the velocity profile is completely *determined* by the position profile in the action, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451) Phys.SE post.

$^2$ For [local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality) theories, the Hamiltonian functional 
$$\mathbb{H}[q,p]~=~\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt~ H(q(t),p(t),t)\tag{8}$$
is just the integral of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Ah, I see, the functional derivative makes more sense! I think this results in the same "Hamiltonian" I provided. The other question still stands: does this Hamiltonian have the same properties as the "usual" Hamiltonian? Also, is it then the case that: $\dot{p}=-\frac{\delta}{\delta q}\int^t_0\mathcal{H}\,\text{d}\tau$ and $\dot{q}=\frac{\delta}{\delta p}\int^t_0\mathcal{H}\,\text{d}\tau$?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Is (4) formulated for a non-local $S$? Or, if the principle were non-local in time (same as mine), would it be: $\mathbb{H}[q,p]~:=~\sup_{v}\left( \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! d\tau~ p(\tau) v((t_f-t_i)-\tau) -  S[q,v]  \right).$

Comment: Eq. (4) is in principle valid for general non-local $S[q,v]$. For specific application (such as e.g. Gurtin-Tonti bi-local convolution theory, cf. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167027/2451) Phys.SE post), it might be convenient to rename/relabel/reflect certain variables, but this is effectively just a notational issue.

Comment: Great! Would you happen to know of any additional sources that deal with the treatment of non-local Lagrangians in this manner?

Comment: I posted a question [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173238/an-inconsistency-in-hamiltonian-formulation-for-non-local-lagrangian-what-am-i/173284#173284) which I ended up answering. I did a derivation which might contradict what (I'm interpreting) you have here.

Comment: Disclaimer: The evolution equation of a non-local system may not predict time-evolution.