# Formulating a symplectic integrator for a non-local Hamiltonian

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, action, numerical-method, non-locality

I recently asked two questions, Q. [[1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173036/legendre-transform-for-non-local-lagrangians-or-hamiltonian-of-non-local-lagran)] and Q. [[2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173238/an-inconsistency-in-hamiltonian-formulation-for-non-local-lagrangian-what-am-i)], regarding reformulating non-local Lagrangians as Hamiltonians.

In these questions, the Hamiltonian is formulated as an integral because of it's non-local nature. Additionally, all of the partial derivatives must be replaced by functional derivatives, for the same reason.

My question is, how does one formulate a symplectic integrator for such a Hamiltonian?

In all symplectic integrator derivations I've seen, the Hamiltonian *function* is used, not the integral. Is there a more generalized approach one can take in this case?

Take for example the case where:

$$
\mathbb{H}=\frac{1}{2}\int^t_0 \left(p(\tau)p(t-\tau)+q(\tau)q(t-\tau)\right)\,\text{d}\tau
\tag{1}$$

This Hamiltonian has the associated Hamilton's equations of (as per Q. [[2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173238/an-inconsistency-in-hamiltonian-formulation-for-non-local-lagrangian-what-am-i)]) :

$$
\dot{q}(\tau)=p(\tau),\,\dot{p}(\tau)=q(\tau)
\tag{2}$$

--

[[1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173036/legendre-transform-for-non-local-lagrangians-or-hamiltonian-of-non-local-lagran)] This question deals with the Legendre transform for non-local Lagrangian formulations.

[[2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173238/an-inconsistency-in-hamiltonian-formulation-for-non-local-lagrangian-what-am-i)] This question (and answer) deals the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equations and Hamilton's equations for non-local Lagrangians.

Comment: I had an answer which I realized was irrelevant; the problem appears to be that you have a field theory and do not realize it. (Hence why functional derivatives are used, the Hamiltonian is an integral expression, etc.)

Comment: @AlexNelson: Can you explain what you mean? I'm fairly new to all this and any input (or a source I can look at) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hamilton's eqs. 
$$\dot{z}^I(t)~\approx~ \{z^I(t), \mathbb{H}\}_{PB},\tag{1}$$
for non-local Hamiltonian theories have the same form as for local theories. Here $\mathbb{H}$ is a (possibly non-local) Hamiltonian functional, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/173075/2451).
It follows that the [symplectic integrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) program carries over essentially un-modified, if
the Hamiltonian functional

$$\mathbb{H}[q,p]~=~\mathbb{T}[p]+\mathbb{V}[q]\tag{2}$$

splits, cf. the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator).

Comment: You're on a roll! This is great. I'll try this out numerically. Based on some of the other answers you've given me, I might run into some problems which might manifest numerically, as a result of some of the analytical things at play here.

Comment: Disclaimer: The evolution equation of a non-local system may not predict time-evolution.