# Energy and canonical momentum conservation in non-local classical field theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, field-theory, variational-principle, non-locality

Assume we have the following Lagrangian field density where $x, x'$ both three dimensional real vectors are coordinates and $t$ represents time, field is given by $\phi$. Assume for the sake of concreteness that $\phi$ is a function that returns three-dimensional real vector.

$$ \mathscr{L} = f(x) (\partial_t\phi)^2 + \int g(x, x', \phi(x), \phi(x')) dx'. $$

Define canonical momentum to be:

$$ \pi = \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial(\partial_t\phi)} = 2f(x)\partial_t\phi. $$

Questions:

1. Is it true that we can write equations of motion as:
   $$ \partial_t \pi_i = - \sum \limits_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} P_{ij}? $$
   Here, $P_{ij}$ is some function.
2. Is there an equivalent law of conservation of energy? How does it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To keep the notation simple let us consider bi-local point-mechanics 
   $$ S[q,v]~=~\int \! dt~dt^{\prime}~{\cal L}(t,t^{\prime}), \tag{A} $$ 
   where we use the shorthand notation
   $$ {\cal L}(t,t^{\prime})~=~{\cal L}(q(t),q(t^{\prime}),v(t),v(t^{\prime}),t,t^{\prime}).\tag{B}$$
   (It is in principle straightforward to generalize to multi-local field theory.)
2. Define momentum
   $$p(t)~:=~\frac{\delta S[q,v]}{\delta v(t)}
   ~=~\int \! dt^{\prime}~\frac{\partial[{\cal L}(t,t^{\prime})+{\cal L}(t^{\prime},t)]}{\partial v(t)},\tag{C}$$
   force
   $$F(t)~:=~\frac{\delta S[q,v]}{\delta q(t)}~=~\int \! dt^{\prime}~\frac{\partial[{\cal L}(t,t^{\prime})+{\cal L}(t^{\prime},t)]}{\partial q(t)},\tag{D}$$
   Lagrangian
   $$ L(t)~:=~\int \! dt^{\prime}~[{\cal L}(t,t^{\prime})+{\cal L}(t^{\prime},t)], \tag{E}$$
   and energy function
   $$ H(t)~:=~p(t)v(t)-L(t).\tag{F}$$
3. Next we identify
   $$\dot{q}(t)~\approx~v(t),\tag{G}$$
   and assume the [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) (SAP). The Lagrangian EOM becomes
   $$\dot{p}(t)~\approx~F(t).\tag{H}$$
4. One may show that if ${\cal L}(t,t^{\prime})$ has no explicit time dependence, then the energy function $H(t)$ is conserved on-shell.
5. For more on non-local action functionals, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173036/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Thanks! 1. Why do you define Lagrangian (and respective quantities) in such a symmetric way? 2. Why is Lagrangian defined not in a way that action is integral of Lagrangian (which I think is the usual convention)? 3. When you write in point 4 that $\mathcal{L}$ has no explicit time dependence do you mean that both partial derivatives are zero?

Comment: 1. The symmetric form comes from the SAP. 2. What you want to call the Lagrangian for non-local theories is not set in stone. The definition (E) is here chosen to have eq. (F). 3. Yes.