# Fourier transform of a functional derivative

Tags: fourier-transform, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Suppose that $x(q)$ is the Fourier transform of the function $x(r)$, where $r$ is the real-space variable and $q$ is the Fourier-space variable. Then, suppose that $E$ is an energy functional which can be differentiated either in real-space (with respect to $x(r)$) or Fourier-space (with respect to $x(q)$).

Representing the Fourier-transform operator as FT[], is the following relation logically valid?

$$\mathrm{FT}\left[\frac{\delta E}{\delta x(r)}\right] = \frac{\delta E}{\delta x(q)}$$

If not, what would be the correct mapping between these functional derivatives?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your notation. Is $x_q$ a function? And is it the Fourier transform of the function $x_r$? If the answers are positive also the answer to your question should be  positive (with a suitable interpretation of the formulae).

Comment: @ValterMoretti Yes, that's right. I have edited the question now to use conventional notation, i.e. $x_q = x(q)$ and $x_r = x(r)$. $x(q)$ is the Fourier transform of the function $x(r)$.

Comment: Hi Ferreroire. Is your question inspired by a particular physical context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Note that if a functional $S[\phi]$ is [local](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121816/2451) in position space with variable $x$, it is typically not [local](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95018/2451) in wavevector space with Fourier transformed variable $k$, where$^1$
   $$\widetilde{\phi}(k)~=~ \int \!d^dx~e^{-ik\cdot x}\phi(k)\tag{1}$$
   is the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).
2. In physical applications, it is often convenient to define [functional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) in $x$- and $k$-space with slightly different conventions for an infinitesimal variation:
   $$\begin{align}\delta S~=~&\int \!d^dx~\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(x)}\delta\phi(x)\cr
   ~=~&\int \!\frac{d^dk}{\color{red}{(2\pi)^d}}~\frac{\delta S}{\delta \widetilde{\phi}(\color{red}{-}k)}\delta\widetilde{\phi}(k),\end{align}\tag{2}$$
   which is inspired by the [Plancherel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem)/[convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).
3. Then it is easy to see that OP's conjecture is correct:
   $$ FT\left[x\mapsto \frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(x)}\right](k)~=~ \frac{\delta S}{\delta \widetilde{\phi}(k)}.\tag{3} $$
4. If one doesn't like to use a different convention (2) for the functional derivative in $k$-space marked in $\rm \color{red}{red}$ color, then the formula (3) will be modified accordingly.

--

$^1$ Here we assume for simplicity a real field $\phi$, and leave to the reader to generalize to a complex field.

Comment: I think that relevant theorem here is not the convolution one, but the Plancherel theorem...

Comment: Thanks @Valter Moretti. Yes, the Plancherel theorem is indeed closer. Edited.

Answer (score 6):

Without paying much attention to mathematical hypotheses (however they can be fixed), your idea is correct in view of the following "proof".
$$E[\hat{x}(q)]= E\left[ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int e^{irq} \hat{x}(q) dr\right]$$
Hence
$$\int \frac{\delta E}{\delta \hat{x}(q)} \hat{h}(q) dq = \frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha=0} E\left[ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int e^{irq} (\hat{x}(q) + \alpha \hat{h}(q)) dr \right] $$
$$=\frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha=0} E\left[ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int e^{irq} \hat{x}(q) dr+ \alpha (2\pi)^{-n/2}\int e^{irq} \hat{h}(q) dr \right] $$
$$ =\frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha=0} E\left[x(r)+ \alpha (2\pi)^{-n/2}\int e^{irq} \hat{h}(q) dr \right] = \int  \frac{\delta E}{ \delta x(r)} 
 \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int e^{irq} \hat{h}(q) dr dq$$
Using the [Plancherel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem), the found integral can be recast to
$$\int \left( \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int e^{-iqr} \frac{\delta E}{ \delta x(r)} dr\right) \:
 \hat{h}(q)  \:dq$$
This identity says that
$$  \frac{\delta E}{\delta \hat{x}(q)}  = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int e^{-iqr} \frac{\delta E}{ \delta x(r)} dr$$
which is your thesis.