# Is it possible to have transformations that transform the action and the measure while leaving the functional integral invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Anomalous symmetries are those for which the Lagrangian stays invariant but the measure of the functional integral does not. I wonder if there are transformations that change both the action and the measure, such that the functional integral is left invariant, is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/231610/2451