# Is the change in the Lagrangian always a total derivative for symmetry transformations of the action?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mathematical-physics, symmetry, action, noethers-theorem

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ and consider an arbitrary functional
$$
S\colon C^k(\Omega)\to\mathbb R
$$
that is local,
$$
\phi\overset S\mapsto \int_\Omega L(\phi,D\phi,\dots,D^k\phi)
$$
for $L$ some $n$-form taking values in the $k$-jet space $J^k\phi$. We may call $S$ the action functional, and $L$ its associated Lagrangian (although we do **not** assume that $\delta S[\phi]=0$, i.e., we work off-shell).

There are two notions of a symmetry that are typically discussed:

1. Lagrangian symmetries, that is, transformations of the form $\phi\to\phi'$ that satisfy
   $$
   L-L'=\mathrm d\Theta
   $$
   for some $(n-1)$-form $\Theta$, and where $L'(J^k\phi)=L(J^k\phi')$.
2. Action symmetries, that is, transformations of the form $\phi\to\phi'$ that satisfy
   $$
   S-S'=0
   $$
   where $S'[\phi]=S[\phi']$.

If we assume that the boundary conditions are such that $\Theta|_{\partial\Omega}=0$, then it is clear that Lagrangian symmetries are also action symmetries.

If we assume that $\Omega$ is "nice-enough" (e.g. star-shaped) then I believe that any action symmetry is also a Lagrangian symmetry, although I would like to have a more precise statement about this fact. In other words, my question is

> Are these two notions of symmetry equivalent? Under what conditions?

Moreover, how much can we weaken the assumptions? For example, can we take $\Omega$ to be simply-connected instead of star-shaped? Can we take $\phi$ to only have weak derivatives instead of strong derivatives?

Comment: N.B.: I am only considering vertical transformations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. OP's definition 1 is often called a [quasi-symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451)$^1$ (QS) of the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$, or equivalently, a QS of the Lagrangian $n$-form 
   $$\mathbb{L}~=~{\cal L}~\mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \ldots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{n-1}.$$
2. OP's definition 2 should be relaxed to a quasi-symmetry (QS) of the action $$S_{\Omega}~=~\int_{\Omega} \mathbb{L} ,$$ where the action is allowed to change with boundary terms. [This is partly because the Noether variations do not necessarily satisfy the boundary conditions that we usually impose when deriving the Euler-Lagrange (EL) eqs.]
3. The following implication is trivial:

   > A QS of the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ is also a QS of the action $S_{\Omega}$.

   OP's main question is

   > What about the opposite direction?

   That's a good question! Assume that we know a transformation is a QS for $S_{\Omega}$ for at least a single fixed integration region $\Omega$. Then it is still possible to conclude that it is a QS of the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ if

   - (i) the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ is [local](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54792/2451) and
   - (ii) if the field configuration space is [contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space).

   This is due to an algebraic Poincare lemma, cf. Ref. 1.  Note in particular that possible topological obstructions live in the field configuration space, not in the spacetime region $\Omega$.
4. *Example.*  Let 
   $$\mathbb{L}~=~L~\mathrm{d}t, \qquad 
   L~=~\frac{1}{2}\left(-ig^{-1}\dot{g}\right)^2
   ~=~\frac{1}{2}\dot{\theta}^2 ,\qquad \Omega~=~[t_i,t_f],$$ where 
   $$g~=~e^{i\theta}~\in~ U(1)~\cong~ S^1$$ 
   is $U(1)$-valued with $|g|=1$. Here $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ is a multi-valued angle variable $\theta\sim \theta+2\pi$, and therefore not a globally well-defined coordinate per se. Note in particular that the field configuration space $S^1$ is *not* contractible.

   Consider an infinitesimal transformation
   $$\delta g ~=~i\varepsilon t~ g, \qquad \delta\theta ~=~-ig^{-1} \delta g~=~\varepsilon t, $$
   where $\varepsilon$ is a $t$-independent infinitesimal parameter.
   The transformation is *not* a QS of the Lagrangian
   $$ \delta L ~=~\varepsilon\dot{\theta}
   ~=~ \varepsilon\left(-ig^{-1}\dot{g}\right), $$
   because it cannot be written as total time derivative using only good coordinates. But the change of the action is
   $$\delta S_{\Omega}~=~\varepsilon(\theta(t_f)-\theta(t_i))$$
   which is a well-defined boundary integral, which is independent of the $\theta$-branch. So the transformation is a QS of the action. The corresponding Noether charge 
   $$ Q~=~t\dot{\theta}-\theta $$
   lacks good coordinates.

References:

1. G. Barnich, F. Brandt and  M. Henneaux, *Local BRST cohomology in gauge theories,* Phys. Rep. 338 (2000) 439, [arXiv:hep-th/0002245](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002245).

--

$^1$ In this answer we will for simplicity only consider *infinitesimal* variations/transformations.