# The Lagrangian of a free particle in Landau & Lifshitz

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, action, galilean-relativity

In Landau & Lifshitz's derivation of the Lagrangian of a free particle  in a galilean frame of reference one finds the following argument: the equations of motion in two galilean frames must be identical; hence the respective Lagrangians must differ by the total derivative of a function of the generalized position, and time. This is essentially the converse of what the authors point to as justification, namely that adding such a term to the Lagrangian leaves the equations unchanged, and I don't really get why it holds. The only relevant answer I found on stackexchange is Qmechanics' take in [Deriving the Lagrangian for a free particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23098/), but i must admit it doesn't quite satisfy me.

**Edit:** I'm asking why modifications of the Lagrangian that don't change the EL equations are necessarily the addition of a total derivative (and multiplication by a scalar), like L&L claims.

Comment: I might be wrong, but using the Euler-Lagrange equations in this context is rather circular, no? What we should be looking to prove is that something that doesn't change the equations is a total derivative, etc., not that something that doesn't change the equations, well, doesn't change the equations. Also the answer I linked gives the final form of the Lagrangian, while Landau uses another argument after the one I mentionned.

Comment: Note that my use of EL eqs. is not circular logic. It is a trick to identify terms which are total derivatives.

Comment: I must admit this is somewhat fuzzy, but I reckon you're not fixing Landau's method but rather yours is different entirely; he says that the Lagrangians must differ by a certain kind of function and then establishes that dL/d(v^2) is a constant, but you say that the difference must obey Euler-Lagrange and then you find a formula for it; or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368801/84967

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131925/2451

Comment: FWIW, L&L do not seem to mention _multiplication by a scalar_ as OP claims (v2).

Comment: Both treads you linked I don't have the prerequisites to understand well.  As for multiplication by a scalar Landau rules it out in paragraph 3 (in the context of two systems, that is). Sorry if I'm being somewhat blunt I don't get why there is no readily available answer to my query; after all, shouldn't it haunt every somewhat mathematically-inclined Landau reader? PS: I think my question is undeserving of the 'unclear' tag.

Comment: If I may add (and surely with due deference to Landau!) the whole derivation is replete with logical errors. When it has been obtained that L is a constant times velocity squared, to prove that the constant is positive the authors seem to use that there is a unique path minimizing the action, without proving nor even mentioning the fact.

Comment: OK. That's eq. (2.7) in $\S2$. Link: http://renaissance.ucsd.edu/courses/mae207/mech.pdf

Answer (score 2):

L&L's logic is as follows:

1. L&L demands$^1$ that an (infinitesimal) [Galilean transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) should be a quasisymmetry (QS) of the sought-for action functional $S$.
2. We furthermore demand that

   - the action functional is local, and
   - the position space is contractible.
3. From [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368801/2451) Phys.SE post, we then deduce that an (infinitesimal) Galilean transformation is in fact a [QS](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) of the Lagrangian $L$ itself. This means by definition that the change $\Delta L$ in the Lagrangian is a total time derivative, as OP wanted to show.

--

$^1$ This is reasonable since Newtonian mechanics has Galilean symmetry. However, there is potentially a loophole since a symmetry of EOM does *not* have to be a QS of the action, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51327/2451) Phys.SE post. Then the bigger question becomes:

> *How much can we change the action without affecting the EOM?*

That's a good question, which was essentially also asked in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131925/2451) Phys.SE post.