# Can a four-divergence be added pure Yang-Mills Lagrangian to alter the action?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, action, boundary-terms

A four-divergence term $\partial_\mu K^\mu$ when added to a Lagrangian, the action changes as $$S\to S^\prime=S+\int_R d^4x \partial_\mu K^\mu\tag{1}$$ where $R$ is a region of spacetime. Using Gauss' theorem, the term $\int_R d^4x \partial_\mu K^\mu$ can be converted to a surface integral $$\int_{\partial R} d\sigma_\mu K^\mu$$  where $\partial R$ represents the boundary of $R$. Now consider a pure Yang-Mills action $$S=-\int d^4x~ \frac{1}{4}G_{\mu\nu}^a G^{\mu\nu a}.$$ We add to it a term $\int_R d^4x \partial_\mu K^\mu$ where $K^\mu$ has the form $$K^\mu=\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}A_\nu^a\Big(G^a_{\lambda\rho}+\frac{g}{3}f^{bca}A_\lambda^b A_\rho^c\Big).$$ Here, $G_{\mu\nu}^a=\partial_\mu A_\nu^a-\partial_\nu A_\mu^a+gf^{abc}A_\mu^b A_\nu^c$ denotes the gluon field strength tensor, $A_\mu^a$ are the gluon gauge fields and $a,b,c$ denote the color index. Therefore, the action changes to \begin{eqnarray}S\to S^\prime &=& S+\int_R d^4x \partial_\mu K^\mu\\
&=& S+\int_{\partial R} d\sigma_\mu K^\mu\\
&=& S+\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}\int_{\partial T}d\sigma_\mu A_\nu^a\Big(G^a_{\lambda\rho}+\frac{g}{3}f^{bca}A_\lambda^b A_\rho^c\Big).\end{eqnarray} Now, if we consider pure gauge i.e., a boundary condition of the form $A_\mu^a\neq 0$ but $G_{\mu\nu}^a=0$ at $\partial R$, we see that the action changes by a nonzero amount $$S^\prime-S=\frac{g}{48\pi^2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda\rho}f^{bca}\int_{\partial R}d\sigma_\mu A_\nu^a A_\lambda^b A_\rho^c\neq 0.$$

**Question** Does this mean that the action can change even if a four-divergence is added to the Lagrangian?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am asking. But often adding a total divergence to Lagrangian doesn't alter the action. Right? This is why in symmetry considerations, we allow that the Lagrangian can change by a 4-divergence so that the action is still unchanged. (Peskin and Schroeder Eq. 2.10) @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: Did I make an incorrect statement in the preceding comment? @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: I do not understand what sort of answer you are looking for here. You have clearly shown that the action changes by a boundary term if you add this divergence to the Lagrangian. Your *"Does this mean that the action can change even if a four-divergence is added to it?"* therefore makes no sense - that's what you just showed! What do you really want to know here?

Comment: When I said "added to it" , I meant "added to the Lagrangian", not to the action. Usually, if a 4-divergence is added to a Lagrangian, the action does not change. After all, symmetry implies invariance of the action; invariance of the action allows us to add a 4-divergence to the Lagrangian. Is that wrong? @ACuriousMind

Comment: All of that may or may not be wrong depending on your definition of *symmetry*. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/51334/50583 for a discussion of (quasi-)symmetries with boundary terms in the action. Please do not wait with your actual question until someone asks in the comments, but actually ask it in the question itself.

Comment: see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368801/84967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For an [action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) to be mathematically well-posed, the [functional/variational derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) $\delta S/\delta A^a_{\mu}$ should exist. Therefore it is necessary to impose appropriate boundary conditions (BCs).
2. In OP's specific case of YM theory with boundary terms (BTs), we leave it as an exercise to work out all possible consistent BCs. Note in particular that BTs in the action may alter the set of consistent BCs. (This last fact is presumably the answer to OP's real question.) One BC that always works mathematically is the [Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition) BC.
3. If 2 action principles [both with (not necessarily the same) consistent BCs] differ by a BT, then the [field equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) are the same, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87628/2451) Phys.SE post.
4. Finally, we should stress that a BC (besides being mathematically consistent) is often also physically motivated.