# Total divergence term in derivation of Noether's theorem

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, action, noethers-theorem

In the Ashok Das QFT book] pg. 212-213 ([pdf](http://gr.xjtu.edu.cn/c/document_library/get_file?p_l_id=21699&folderId=2383653&name=DLFE-82650.pdf)), the section on Noether's theorem,  the author considered general infinitesimal transformations of the form
$$x^\mu\rightarrow x'^\mu,$$
$$\phi(x)\rightarrow\phi'(x'),$$
$$\partial_\mu\phi(x)\rightarrow\partial'_\mu\phi'(x')\tag{6.3}$$
where $x^\mu$ are spacetime coordinates and $\phi(x)$ is a field.

For such transformations, the invariance of the action $S$ would imply
$$\delta S=\int d^4x' \mathcal L(\phi'(x'),\partial'_\mu\phi'(x')) - \int d^4x\mathcal L(\phi(x),\partial_\mu\phi(x))=0,$$
or,
$$\delta S= \int d^4x \mathcal L(\phi'(x),\partial'_\mu\phi'(x)) - \int d^4x\mathcal L(\phi(x),\partial_\mu\phi(x))=0,$$
$$\delta S= \int d^4x [\mathcal L(\phi'(x),\partial'_\mu\phi'(x)) - \mathcal L(\phi(x),\partial_\mu\phi(x))]=0.\tag{6.7}$$

The author then said that the last equality will hold if
$$\mathcal L(\phi'(x),\partial'_\mu\phi'(x)) - \mathcal L(\phi(x),\partial_\mu\phi(x))=\partial_\mu K^\mu,\tag{6.8}$$
where $\partial_\mu K^\mu$ is a total divergence.

Why is that so? According to the Gauss theorem, for the integral $\int\partial_\mu K^\mu d^4x$ to vanish, $K^\mu$ needs to vanish at the surface boundary, which I assume is at infinity. How can we be sure that $K^\mu$ will vanish at infinity when we don't know what $K^\mu$ is?

Comment: This is usually an assumption (either that $K$ vanishes on the boundary or that there is no boundary). In certain cases, such as for gravitational theories, this is however not the case (cf. Gibbons-Hawking-York term).

Comment: As a general rule, if not otherwise stated, all quantities are sufficiently smooth. This does not mean that from surface terms cannot come interesting physics, but most of the times they do not have an immediate effect.

Comment: It is often assumed that the field $\phi$ vanishes in infity sufficiently fast. But you're right, in general this surface term at infity may be relevant, and sometimes it's important.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/368801/2451