Locality in statistical field theory
In a lot of introductions to Landau-Ginzburg theory, which gives the partition function in the form of a functional integral $$\mathcal{Z}[F]=\int \mathcal{D}\phi e^{-\beta F(\phi)}$$
it is said that a "locality" condition can be invoked to write $F$ as $$F(\phi)=\int d^nx f(\phi,\nabla \phi,...)$$
where $f$ can depend on the field and its derivatives. Why is this called locality? It is said that enforcing this guarantees  that, for example, in the Ising model, only nearest neighbours affect each other directly, but I can't see why.

You do not have terms like $\phi(x)\phi(x')$ in $F$. These would be ?on local (and could be physical). However, if you want your system to interact with its neighboorood and be local, you just use gradients

I guess that kind of makes sense, but I wanted to see more directly how that constrains the interactions to be local.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95018/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54792/2451 and links therein.

One way to see this intuitively is that the field theory is the continuum limit of the exact system. Thus going back to a discrete system can be seen as approx. replacing derivatives by finite shift operators where $\nabla \sim $ shift by one unit cell.  Thus any term with $\nabla^n$ will correspond to a local interaction in the lattice picture.
